# Как подсчитать нули в массиве?

Tags: java, массивы

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] mass = {0,1,-1,0,1,0,-1,-1,-1,1,0,0,0,1,-1,0};
   int MinusOne = 0;
   int Zero = 0;
   int PlusOne = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mass.length - 1; i++) {
  if (mass[i] == -1){MinusOne++;} continue;

  if (mass[i] == 0){ Zero++;} continue; //Error:unreachable statement MARK1 

  if (mass[i] == 1){PlusOne++;} continue;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Почему вылетает ошибка?

Comment: Александр, вы же понимаете русский?

Comment: `continue` под `{` внесите...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (mass[i] == -1){MinusOne++;} continue;
```

Вы выполняете безусловный continue:

```
if (mass[i] == -1){MinusOne++;} 
continue;
```

Область действия управляющих конструкций(условного оператора в том числе) ограниченна одним оператором.
Таким оператором может являться блок кода (`{ ... }`)

Должно быть так:

```
if (mass[i] == -1){MinusOne++; continue;}
```

И это, разумеется, касается всех подобных конструкций ниже.

Comment: Спасибо!Мой затуп...